# extending EBS volume

Tags: windows, amazon-ebs, diskmanagement, aws-ec2, expansion

I have extended an existing EBS volume from 2.5Tb to 3 Tb , However when i check disk managment I dont see the unallocted space , It shows as 3TB post extension in AWS console but not on my windows server

One thing to note is that there seem to be drive name mismatch , For ex the its named xvde in aws but in the server the drive name is something else its not the E drive , Rather its the F drive

can this be causing an issue ? If not is there a way to overcome this

Comment: if the [volume expansion finished](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-modifications.html) and you still don't see the space in the OS you should probably contact support.

Comment: Did you do a rescan of the disks in disk management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall on this I started reading the documentation and there was a point mentioned about servers with NVMe drivers missing require a reboot for the unallocated space to show up and it was indeed the case , the server didnt have the NVMe storage adaptger driver which is the reason the unallocated space was not showing up , I never came across this issue before so didnt think of a reboot , Finally after reboot it got fixed

Answer (score 0):

> "Note ::"?

Did you resize the partition and the filesystem after you changed the size of the drive? Use the disk management utility to do this.

(You can also do this from the command line *in some cases* using diskpart.exe but the free space must be at the end of the partition to be resized, and this cannot be the partition the OS is installed on.

Comment: Hi , For me to resize the partition there should be a an unallocated space of 500 GB in my case showing up in the first place for me to extend the drive , This is a standard work I have done many times , Its the first time where I have extended the EBS volume and the unallocated data dosent show up in disk managment ,  I have already tried diskpart but as you have already mentioned free space should be at the end  of partition which in this case is not showing up and no its not the OS partition

Comment: Was the resize successful? I've seen operations fail in AWS without reporting an error - particularly on asynchronous operations like disk resizes.